# different count using ps and wc to check if service is running in bash

Tags: bash, wc

I have a small script to check if a service is running in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

countlines=""$(ps -ef | grep netdata | grep -v grep | wc -l)

echo $countlines >> mylog.log

if [ ${countlines} -lt 3 ];then

sudo /bin/systemctl restart netdata

fi
```

The problem is when I issue a `ps -ef | grep netdata | grep -v grep | wc -l` at the command line the result is always `3` but mylog.log is:

```
6
```

[update: added filtered ps -ef results]

```
forge@reportserver:~ ps -ef | grep netdata
netdata  22308     1  0 08:38 ?        00:00:37 /usr/sbin/netdata -D
netdata  22386 22308  0 08:38 ?        00:00:58 /usr/libexec/netdata/plugins.d/apps.plugin 1
netdata  47045 22308  0 11:38 ?        00:00:02 bash /usr/libexec/netdata/plugins.d/tc-qos-helper.sh 1
forge    52028 27902  0 12:34 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto netdata
```

why such a discordance?

Comment: probably this is because you're using append (>>) sign.

Comment: @Mahdia the problem is that OP got `3` in their command, but `6` in their log file

Comment: This: `countlines=""$(ps -ef | grep netdata | grep -v grep | wc -l)` can be resumed to: `countlines=$(ps -ef | grep -c netdat[a])`

Comment: The combination of `ps` and `grep` is called [`pgrep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep).

Comment: that is @Mahdia, the issue is the different count, not the append. Changed question to clear it up

Comment: I ran your code and it works well.Can you post output of `ps -ef`?

Comment: updated question with ps -ef | grep netdata

Answer (score 0):

split into 2 commands to see why:

```
ps_grep_output=$(ps -ef | grep netdata | grep -v grep)

echo "$ps_grep_output" >> mylog.log

countlines=$(wc -l <<< "$ps_grep_output")

echo "$countlines" >> mylog.log
```

Comment: same results with your suggestion @Nahuel

Comment: could you see which lines are differing when executing from command line

Comment: all of them Nahuel